# Is it possible to use edebug for toggle-debug-on-error?

Tags: edebug

edebug seems to be much nicer than the regular debug.

Can I use edebug when `toggle-debug-on-error` ?

Comment: `C-h v debugger` says that it's bound to `debug` by default. It is used in the `call_debugger` function in `src/eval.c` so it is conceivable that you can modify it so that `edebug` is called instead. But I have not tried it out, so maybe you can and write your own answer if it works.

Comment: @NickD Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried, but edebug has notion of `instrumentation` Although I'm not sure what it is, it seems edebug needs to process the function somehow and know about it before it can debug.  So I guess it can't be done. 

The way I see is, you use toggle-debug-on-error and find out what function is causing the problem and then you have to use edebug-defun, I guess that's about the best it can be done..